# what does the global objects mean in spidermonkey and what is the role of both JS_class and JS_NewGlobalObject ?

Tags: javascript, c++, spidermonkey, jsapi

I was reading SpiderMonkey tutorial of how to embed and execute javascript code in c++ program via JSAPI spidermoneky. 
but I didn't totally understand what does the global objects do and what is the role of both JS_class and JS_NewGlobal? 
also what does it mean by customizing your global objects?

Comment: Please provide a link to the doc that you're reading.

Comment: Sorry, here is the document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide

Comment: [SpiderMonkey - JSAPI User Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20210528173125/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_User_Guide) document archived by Wayback Machine (archive.org)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you have a top level namespace which actually has properties similar to normal javascript objects, so it is called the "global object". What you normally think of as global variables in a language like C are generally properties of the global object. Top level functions also live there, which is why you see bindings for top-level things like `srand` and `system` being created for the global object in that document. You might want to put different functions in different global environments. Embedders like to do all kinds of customization things.

`JS_Class` is a SpiderMonkey concept for a native type that backs objects in the JS runtime. When you want to make a new, special builtin type you do so by defining a JS_Class, and then objects instantiated from the class can have their class tested in native code to see if it matches. HTH!

Comment: you wrote "In JavaScript you have a top level namespace which actually has properties similar to normal javascript objects," is there a difference between JavaScript and javascript, or you mean spidermonkey.Regarding the global object, what I understood till this moment, is that it includes the top level function that are used by the embedded javascript code, that will be passed to c++ spidermonkey code, so for example if embedded java script code needs foo function it will call the foo in the global object, is this right ? 
and if I want to write codes and use spidermonkey, what should i do ?